# How to publish ASP.NET 3.5 on IIS 5.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, publishing, iis-5

I am using visual studio 2008 fo rasp .net 3.5 web development. I published the website and added virtual directory in IIS 5.1 built in windows xp.

When i run the page, the following error is displayed.

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'http://localhost/cdt/Dashboard.aspx'. Line 1, Pos...

<%@ page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_zy4yhpyn" ...
```

Do i have to install anything else?

why is this happening?

What is the solution?

UPDATE: Chose .net 2.0 version. (there is no option such as 3.5 in IIS 5.1)(Should i install a higher version?)

Ran it again and now get this error:

`Failed to access IIS metabase. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

Exception Details: System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentException: Failed to access IIS metabase.

EDIT:
ok. I found the error.

Solved it by reinstalling ASP at http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/02/failed-to-access-iis-metabase.html

great!

Comment: why IIS 5.1? why are you not using 7+?

Comment: since it was pre installed in windows xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason the aspx files are not rendered properly. try registering asp.net using ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe u- uninstall, i-install) once again. Also check the version of asp.net in the IIS.

Comment: should i execute id dos? it is not recognised in dos

Comment: this must be run in visual studio command prompt.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: executed and working! though another error :( updated in edit.